# Which software can automatically detect subtitles match with dialogue?

Tags: programming, synchronization, artificial-intelligence, subtitles

I have the subtitles already but there are some lines doesn't match up with the dialogue and there are some line do match up so I want ask is there a program can know which lines of subtitles know which lines need to be changed to match up with dialogue and subtitles togather? I don't want to change all the line because maybe there some line do match up with the dialogue. Is there an AL can automatically synchronize?